# User input to update a object in a record

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

My data model:

I have a object called skill review which has skill__c,level__c as a lookup fields. I have a interview object which has skill review in a related list. I have a visualforce page where I have a level variable as a selectList. I would like the level(1-5) entered by the user to be updated in Level__c object of skill Review object. Below is my VF page and controller for that:

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Interview__c" extensions="SkillReviewExtension" showHeader="false">

  <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock title="Candidate Skill Evaluation" id="skills_list">

           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! SkillReview }" var="ct" >      
               <apex:column value="{! ct.Skill__c}"/>
               <apex:column value="{! ct.Level__c}"/>
               <apex:column headerValue="Level">
                   <apex:selectList value="{!Level}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!isEditMode}">
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!Level}"/>       
               </apex:column>
               <apex:column headerValue="Description">

               </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class SkillReviewExtension{

    private final Interview__c review;
    public  boolean isEditMode {get;private set;}
    public String Level{get;set;}
    List<SkillReview> skillReviewList;


     public SkillReviewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.review= (Interview__c)stdController.getRecord();
        }

    public List<Skill_Review__c> getSkillReview() {
        skillReviewList=new List<skillReview>();

        List<Skill_Review__c> results = [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Level__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:review.id ];


        system.debug(results.size());

        //Level=results[0].Level__r.Description__c;
        //skillReviewList.skillReview[0]=results.clone();
        return results;    
    }


    public PageReference save(){
        isEditMode=false;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference edit(){
        isEditMode=true;
        return null;
    }  

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your screenshot i assume there are 5 records in `Level__c` object with Names as 1,2,3,4,5.

So instead of hardcoding `SelectOption` values i would create a method to pull the `Id` and `Name` of `Level__c` records to populate `SelectOption` as below

```
public List<SelectOption> getOptions(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(Level__c level : [Select Id,Name From Level__C Order by Name limit 5]){
        options.add(new SelectOption(level.Id,level.Name));
    }
    return options;
}
```

In Visualforce page will change this

```
<apex:selectList value="{!Level}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!isEditMode}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

to

```
<apex:selectList value="{!ct.Level__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!isEditMode}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: When I do this I get Level as 1,1,1,2,2. I would like to display 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: If you have 3 records with 1 as Name in Level__c object, which record you want to map to Level__c field in Skill Review object if user select 1 in picklist? Any one record or any specific record?

Comment: I have only one record with 1 as a name. There are 5 unique record with 1,2,3,4 and 5 as a name.

Comment: Please recheck your records. There is 3 records with 1 as Name that's why query returns like that and thus the selectlist populates it.

Answer (score 1):

This controller (unrelated stuff stripped out) will keep the `Skill_Review__c` objects in the view state so the changes made in the page are automatically set back in the collection in the controller and so can be directly updated in the `save` method:

```
public class SkillReviewExtension {

    public List<Skill_Review__c> skillReview {get; private set;}

    public SkillReviewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        Interview__c review = (Interview__c) sc.getRecord();
        this.skillReview = [
                select Id, Name, Skill__c, Level__c
                from Skill_Review__c
                where Interview__c = :review.id
                order by Skill__c
                ];
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update skillReviewList;
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Visualforce is then:

```
<apex:selectList value="{! ct.Skill__c }" multiselect="false" size="1">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

This is assuming the `Skill__c` field is not a picklist field; if it was `apex:inputField` could be used and the options would be automatically provided.

Comment: Thanks. How would this update the level__c lookup field on skill review object? Skill__c and Level__c are different object. I need the user entered level string to be updated in the Level__c object and updated in the database. So basically I am capturing the level entered by the user in a record(Level__c)

Comment: @Rdvsm The code I posted will update Skill_Review__c.Skill__c with the selected value thanks to how Visualforce automatically updates controller fields from HTML form fields. Unfortunately your screen shot doesn't show the type of that Skill_Review__c.Skill__c field and your description can be interpreted more than one way. If Skill_Review__c.Skill__c is a lookup field to another object incorporate Vigneshwaran G's answer.

Comment: Sorry, it does not solve my requirement here. I am trying to update the level__c field on Skill_review__c object using the level drop drown entered by the user. Any help with that will be appreciated.